# Netbeans create Java source files in a C/C++ project

Tags: netbeans

I have recently started using Netbeans C/C++. I see that the new file wizard doesn't show any buttons to create java files, all of them disabled. I can create java files in a Java project however.

If I create a java file manually and open it inside the ide, it provides syntax-highlighting. But the IDE doesn not show any wizards that will enable me to create new java files inside a c/c++ project.

How can I enable this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create Java files in a C / C++ project (and vice versa) . You have to use either Java or C(++).

I don't see a reason why you should mix them, but better you develop your Java code in a Java Project and same for C/C++. However, you have to move manually.

Btw. please explain your problem more detailed, it's hard to understand why you put two (or 3) totally different things together.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, I figured it was a paradigm thing, but I couldn't explain it to myself. In a JNI project I could just use a make file to build java and c/c++ files and therefore but both source files in one project. If somebody asks me  why I created two projects to achieve one goal, how would I explain my actions ?

Comment: I see, already expected JNI. You can make a Makefile / CMake Project, at leas CMake supports Java and C/C++. If somebody asks you, why you use two different projects, your answer may be: Because it separates Java (= Platformindepended) from native code. While you don't have to care about Platforms with Java very much, you have to deal with it on C/C++. As a compromise you also can create a project for Java and one for native (C/C++), as well as a "Masterproject" or Buildscript, which builds all at once.

Comment: In a NetBeans tutorial, they separate both Languages too: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/beginning-jni-linux.html

Comment: Thankyou, I saw the link you posted earlier, but I couldn't find the justification for the paradigm they chose. Using CMake however doesn't ensure that the `Java new File Menu` is enabled or provide `code completion for java`, right ?

Comment: I guess not. Did you check to manually create those files and open them afterwards?

Comment: Yes I did, it does provides syntax highlighting, but I am doubtful it provides code completion for third party libraries.

Comment: If this is still relevant, you can check this plugin: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/56247/mixed-java-cpp-development-support

Answer (score 0):

An observation, rather than a solution...

We need to support mixed language projects because the dependancies between artefacts-by-language can go in both directions.

For example: Java classes are used to generate JNI headers (`javah`) for C/C++, while C/C++ headers/libraries are used to generate wrapper classes (`swig`) for Java.

This represents a bidirectional dependancy between single-language projects, but not between artefacts in a single mixed language project - i.e. the build can be described by a DAG and thus satisfied by `make`.